# How can I link to a :download: file on a network drive in Sphinx?

Tags: hyperlink, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I'm making some project documentation for one of our hardware products. The documentation is for internal use, and it is located on a network drive:

`\\ourserver\projects\project1-doc`

The way we currently do version control, we have some folders like so:

```
\\ourserver\projects\project1-A
\\ourserver\projects\project1-B
\\ourserver\projects\project1-C
```

I want to be able to make a `:download:` link from the documentation to a pdf in one of those folders. Is there any way I can do a absolute path to the file? I've tried many things, for example:

```
:download:`schematic <file://///ourserver/projects/project1-C/schematic.pdf>`
:download:`schematic //ourserver/projects/project1-C/schematic.pdf>`
```

but I couldn't get it to work with Sphinx. How can I link to this file?

Answer (score 1):

The document is hosted on the network, but do you build it through sphinx on the network? When using the :download: directive sphinx copies the files to the _build/html directory under _downloads and links to them there. So if you were to build the sphinx doc locally and it can't find the correct file to copy and link during the build then it wont create links, same if the path is wrong.

Anyways, since you are linking to files under version control, you will probably want to create a absolute path with the .. raw:: directive, so that you are always linked to the latest version.

```
.. raw:: html

   <p><a class="reference download internal" href="/ourserver/projects/project1-C/schematic.pdf">
   <tt class="xref download docutils literal">
   Project 1-C Schematic
   </tt></a><p>
```

And if you wanted to link to the pdf and launch it with a created pdf through sphinx. You could use a .. raw:: latex directive.

```
.. raw:: latex

   \href{run:/ourserver/projects/project1-C/schematic.pdf}{Project 1-C Schematic}
```

Custom directives could also be built to make this more fluid.